# How to run the SAP Cloud SDK Pipeline on Kubernetes

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

Currently, I am trying to set up the SAP Cloud SDK on a Kubernetes cluster using the tutorial found here:

https://blogs.sap.com/2018/09/26/autoscaling-of-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-continuous-delivery-toolkit-on-kubernetes/

The setup works fine and I am able to configure and start a pipeline. It also spawns and connects successfully to a new POD running as an agent. However, during the mvn clean install step, a container execution is done on the POD, but this for some unkown reason fails.

I followed the troubleshooting hints in the tutorial, especially checking the connectivity with the Kubernetes cluster via the test Jenkinsfile, but that runs through successfully and does not seem to be the problem. I also tried to check the logs of the container-exec container on the POD, but nothing is returned (for the jnlp container I get the log showing the successful connection).

In the build pipeline the following log statements are given:

```
16:44:02  --- Begin library step of: dockerExecute ---
expected to call com.sap.piper.analytics.Telemetry$_getInstance_closure1.call but wound up catching com.sap.piper.analytics.Telemetry.piperOsDefaultReporting; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/pipeline-cps-method-mismatches/
[Pipeline] timeout
16:44:02  Timeout set to expire in 10 sec
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] httpRequest
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timeout
[Pipeline] echo
16:44:02  --- Begin library step of: dockerExecuteOnKubernetes ---
expected to call com.sap.piper.analytics.Telemetry$_getInstance_closure1.call but wound up catching com.sap.piper.analytics.Telemetry.piperOsDefaultReporting; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/pipeline-cps-method-mismatches/
[Pipeline] timeout
16:44:02  Timeout set to expire in 10 sec
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] httpRequest
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timeout
[Pipeline] stash
16:44:05  Stashed 115 file(s)
[Pipeline] podTemplate
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] node
16:44:20  Still waiting to schedule task
16:44:20  ‘dynamic-agent-7eb57391-be34-4e11-b2e7-e4c3c79e8da1-3lnfp-lwv8q’ is offline
16:44:26  Agent dynamic-agent-7eb57391-be34-4e11-b2e7-e4c3c79e8da1-3lnfp-lwv8q is provisioned from template Kubernetes Pod Template
16:44:26  Agent specification [Kubernetes Pod Template] (7eb57391-be34-4e11-b2e7-e4c3c79e8da1): 
16:44:26  yaml:
16:44:26  {
16:44:26      "apiVersion": "v1",
16:44:26      "kind": "Pod",
16:44:26      "metadata": {
16:44:26          "lables": "7eb57391-be34-4e11-b2e7-e4c3c79e8da1"
16:44:26      },
16:44:26      "spec": {
16:44:26          "containers": [
16:44:26              {
16:44:26                  "name": "jnlp",
16:44:26                  "image": "s4sdk/jenkins-agent-k8s:latest"
16:44:26              },
16:44:26              {
16:44:26                  "name": "container-exec",
16:44:26                  "image": "maven:3.5-jdk-8-alpine",
16:44:26                  "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
16:44:26                  "env": [
16:44:26                      
16:44:26                  ],
16:44:26                  "command": [
16:44:26                      "/usr/bin/tail",
16:44:26                      "-f",
16:44:26                      "/dev/null"
16:44:26                  ]
16:44:26              }
16:44:26          ],
16:44:26          "securityContext": {
16:44:26              
16:44:26          }
16:44:26      }
16:44:26  }
16:44:26  
16:44:27  Running on dynamic-agent-7eb57391-be34-4e11-b2e7-e4c3c79e8da1-3lnfp-lwv8q in /home/piper/workspace/address-manager_master
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
16:44:27  ContainerConfig: [name:container-exec]
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
16:44:27  Unstash content: workspace-7eb57391-be34-4e11-b2e7-e4c3c79e8da1
[Pipeline] unstash
[Pipeline] echo
16:44:31  [INFO][dockerExecute] Executing inside a Kubernetes Pod
[Pipeline] sh
16:49:39  process apparently never started in /home/piper/workspace/address-manager_master@tmp/durable-bc02ec77
16:49:39  (running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)
[Pipeline] sh
16:54:47  process apparently never started in /home/piper/workspace/address-manager_master@tmp/durable-1f05b1bc
16:54:47  (running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)
[Pipeline] echo
16:54:47  script returned exit code -2
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] unstash
[Pipeline] echo
16:54:48  No such saved stash ‘container-7eb57391-be34-4e11-b2e7-e4c3c79e8da1’
[Pipeline] libraryResource
[Pipeline] echo
16:54:48  ----------------------------------------------------------
16:54:48  --- An error occurred in the library step: dockerExecuteOnKubernetes
16:54:48  ----------------------------------------------------------
16:54:48  
16:54:48  The following parameters were available to the step:
16:54:48  ***
16:54:48  [script:Script1@1f99bbb0, dockerImage:maven:3.5-jdk-8-alpine, dockerPullImage:true, stashContent:[]]
16:54:48  ***
16:54:48  
16:54:48  The error was:
16:54:48  ***
16:54:48  hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code -2
16:54:48  ***
16:54:48  
16:54:48  Further information:
16:54:48  * Documentation of library step dockerExecuteOnKubernetes: https://sap.github.io/jenkins-library/steps/dockerExecuteOnKubernetes/
16:54:48  * Source code of library step dockerExecuteOnKubernetes: https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-library/blob/master/vars/dockerExecuteOnKubernetes.groovy
16:54:48  * Library documentation: https://sap.github.io/jenkins-library/
16:54:48  * Library repository: https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-library/
16:54:48  
16:54:48  ----------------------------------------------------------
16:54:48  --- End library step of: dockerExecuteOnKubernetes ---
```

I know the feature is marked as experimental in the blog entry, but I was able to successfully set up such a scenario some months back, so someting seems to have changed. Is this still a valid scenario to operate the pipeline? Any hints on how to proceed and make this work would be really appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any errors in the plugin page ? Could you please paste the log from the line that reads as “start step dockerExecute.groovy” ?

Comment: Added the missing logs, sorry for that, should have thought about this myself. On the plugin page there are no errors being shown.

Comment: Thanks for the log. It appears that the maven command cannot be executed inside the container in the pod. Could you please write a few lines about your infrastructure setup? Are you using any Volume claims? If yes, what kind of PVC are they? RWone or RW many.

Comment: The setup is on a Google Cloud GKE cluster. I more or less simply created that and used the default values for the helm chart as mentioned in the blog:
https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/jenkins/values.yaml

Only made some minor adaptations:
* changed the images to those of s4sdk jenkins master and jenkins k8s agent
* removed the plugins from the values.yml, as it seems to have overwritten the ones installed via the jenkins master image
* removed the hardware limits of the agent

So no volume claims have been explicitly configured...

Comment: I could reproduce the issue on GKE, I will update you once I have a fix. Thanks for bringing this to our notice.

Comment: Could you please confirm the port mappings for service port and contaierPort ? This issue disappeared on GKE when I mapped the servicePort to 80 (default is 8080). We have an end-to-end guide to help the user to build and deploy an SAP S/4 HANA extension application to  SCP with CI/CD setup on GKE. Please check if this could give you more information https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-sap-hana-s4sdk-k8/#2

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the servicePort to 80 didn't solve the issue. I checked all other steps in your link and even set up my Jenkins from skretch, but did not help either. BTW: I think you missed a step for setting up the ON_K8S variable (it's part of the values.yaml, but for the backup, not the jenkins). When I ran the job without the ON_K8S variable it had two problems: docker doesn't seem to be running on the master (Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?) and mvn isn't found (mvn: not found). Both seems strange to me as well...

Comment: Just tried to run the job again, and while it got stuck in the dockerOnKubernetesExecute I opened a shell in the container-exec to show the processes. The following was shown: `root          11       1  0 07:24 ?        00:00:00 [sh] <defunct>`, so it seems the command crashes somehow

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. It was bit tricky to debug. Could you please update the jnlp image in the pipeline configuration and check? as shown here https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-book/blob/K8S/pipeline_config.yml#L5. The problem was due to the change in the jenkins work directory assumption by the newer plugin version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided change in the comments did the trick. A simple change of the pipeline_config.yaml to use a different image:

https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-book/blob/K8S/pipeline_config.yml#L5

Afterwards everything ran through just fine.