# jenkins pipeline running inside docker image just hangs

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a very simple script to test running inside a docker container.
The container starts and I can connect to the container.

```
node('docker') {
    docker.image('python:3').inside() {
        sh "python --version"
    }
}
```

In the end the job fails. Any ideas what is wrong?

---

Update 1:

I have added the environment variable to Jenkins and now see the following. Looks like some strange variables are passed to docker.
Any idea how I can examine the command given in the `sh`?

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] echo
I'm here
[Pipeline] sh
invalid argument "=" for "-e, --env" flag: invalid environment variable: =
See 'docker exec --help'.
process apparently never started in /var/lib/jenkins- 
slave/workspace/SYSTEM/clean-artifactory@tmp/durable-4d51de81
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

Comment: Which version of the jenkins-slave are you using? I encountered this with the latest version of the durable task plugin and the old Jenkins agent. However, I am using the kubernetes environment, not the docker. But the error was the same. It got resolved after I changed the agent. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56963559/how-to-run-the-sap-cloud-sdk-pipeline-on-kubernetes?noredirect=1#comment100503031_56963559

Comment: 3.29, let me have a look if I can update this

Comment: `3.29-2` works for us. we are also using the same version.

Comment: I launch it using ssh, so the remoting.jar is automatically deployed. Could it be a java version issue?

Comment: Was this working before? If yes, I would revert the recent plugin updates. I am certain that it has to do with the durable task plugin update. Could you include `echo` statement before `sh` and see if it works?  I will also try replacing `sh` with  `sh(returnStdout: true, script: "pwd")` and see if there is a change in the behavior.

Comment: I just have a working solution on our K8S environment, but honestly, I did not get a chance to identify the root cause.

Comment: The echo before the `sh` works but the shell script still doesn't. I have downgraded the Durable Task plugin and now get an error about invalid arguments being passed to docker. I think I will setup a clean Jenkins instance to test this further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a bug in the Durable Task plugin and has been fixed by the latest release ([1.33](https://github.com/jenkinsci/durable-task-plugin/releases/tag/durable-task-1.33)).

See [JENKINS-59903](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-59903)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and after a long wait this error message is logged in console:

```
Cannot contact : java.io.FileNotFoundException: File '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject@2@tmp/durable-1a2d497f/output.txt' does not exist
```

The problem is `Durable Task` plugin. In my case I downgraded `Durable Task` plugin from latest (1.31) to 1.30 and that solved the problem.

I'm using `Docker Pipeline` version 1.21

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about this and found out that there was a new release of the plugin just 2 days ago that fixed this. Give it a try.